# Command for loop appending command name to files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have an executable file, call it exec1.exe

I have a bunch of files with a .txt extension and I want to run exec1.exe on it and redirect output to a text file with the original file name somewhere in the output file.  I'm running the command

```
for %i in (mydir\\*.txt) do exec1 %i > "%i2.txt"
```

But this tries to run on the first text file text1.txt,

```
exec1 exec1text1.txt > exec1text1.txt2.txt
```

But I want

```
exec1 text1.txt > text1.txt2.txt
```

Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: Do a `dir mydir\\*.txt` to make sure your filenames are as you expect,

Comment: When I replace exec1 with echo, everything works fine and the files are appropriately named

Comment: To be precise, I also have additional arguments, so I'm actually running something along the lines of "do exec1 -y 754 %i  > "%i2.txt"  Could this be the problem?

Comment: Don't think that should make a difference. Try enclosing %i in quotes `"%i"`

Comment: It *ought* to say something like `exec1 mydir\\text1.txt`, if you don't want the path use `%~nxi`

Comment: With "%i" it's still trying to execute on exec1text1.txt

Comment: A single `\ `is sufficient as path separator in `cmd`. To get the pure file name (`text1` without extension `.txt`) use `%~ni` rather than `%i`/`%~i`. To use the `for` loop in a batch file, double the percent signs, like `%%i`. Anyway, if your loop really iterates `mydir\\text1.txt`, the executed line is going to be `exec1 mydir\\text1.txt > "mydir\\text1.txt2.txt"`!

Answer (score 0):

You could probably get away with this, *(double up the `%` if running from a batch file)*:

```dos
for %i in ("mydir\*.txt") do @start "" exec1.exe -y 754 "%i">"%~ni2.txt"
```

**Note**

I have used `%~ni2` instead of `%i2` to write to the current directory. This is because your command would be outputting to `.txt` whilst reading `*.txt`. An alternative would be to use a different known path, e.g. `>"known\%i2.txt`

Comment: This has not been working for me either.  I'm producing files that look like text1.txt.text2.txt

Comment: Can you provide the real name of the executable and the exact commands you are using. It's almost impossible to fix if you aren't actually inputting the same responses we're giving you.